# Slow save in elasticsearch repository

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) and I have two entity classes:

```
@Document(indexName = "aa", type = "aa", shards = 5, replicas = 1, refreshInterval = "-1", indexStoreType = "memory")
class AA {

     @Id
     private Long Id;

     private BB bb;
     private String field1;

     // ... Many more Fields.

     // ... getters and setters
}

@Document(indexName = "bb", type = "bb", shards = 5, replicas = 1, refreshInterval = "-1", indexStoreType = "memory")
class BB {

     @Id
     private Long Id;

     private BB bbParent;

     // ... Many more Fields.

     // ... getters and setters
}
```

When I'm saving  to AA repository

```
aaRepository.save(aa);
```

I have strange behavior: when bbParent is null, everything is fine, but when bbParent is set, saving takes much (>100 times) longer.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: it looks like recursive BB class creating problem, but it can be something else as well. can you share some more code please ? or probable entire project on github ?

Comment: sorry, but I'm not able to make github project now. problem was that saving to ES repository take a while when my aa objects is very big. do you know is there a annotation so I can exclude some fields when saving to ES repository?